# Difference between PDE and ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, definition

So, this year I have an ODE course. We have defined what an ODE is but we haven't done it for PDE. Our definition was simply:

Let I be an open interval. We call "an ODE from $n$-th order" an equation which has the form $F(t,x,x',x'',...,x^{(n)})=0$ where $x: I\to \Bbb R^m$ is called the "unknown" of the function $F: I\times \Bbb R^{m\cdot(n+1)}\to \Bbb R^m$.

The derivatives don't count as an unknown because we can find them after finding what function $x$ is.

In our definiton, $t$ is taken from $I$. What will be for PDE? Will it be something like $F(t,s,x,x',x'',...,x^n)=0$  ?

Of course I could find a definiton on google. But I couldn't find a PDE definitions which looks similar to ODE definition I mentioned. Like this, I can truly understand the difference.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to use LATEX

Comment: please check if my edit is correct

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you so much for editing

Comment: Shouldn’t $F:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^{n+1}\to\Bbb R$? What’s the “$m$”?

Comment: If you want to say F: R→R^(n+1), it means that m=1 in this case. m determines the "dimension" of the function. For example: f(t)= (t,t²). For any t from R, the function maps t with an element of R²

Comment: It must be $x:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m,$ then (instead of $x:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Ah, yes. You are right, can you help me editing the question?

Comment: Done. However, I really recommend to learn the basics of MathJax, such that you will be able to do such edits (and to write better questions and answers) in the future, in case you need it.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, It's a must for math students. I just can't find time to learn it, but I'll try. :)

Comment: I also fixed the domain and image of $F$. The image must be $\mathbb{R}^m$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, otherwise the system of equations would be underdetermined.

Comment: Hmm... But our F function must return a real number. If this real number equals to 0, that means the equation is satisfied. Else, equation won't be satisfied.

Comment: In your PDE, if $x$ is a function of two variables $s$ and $t$, then you must allow all derivatives of the form $\partial^{j+k} x/\partial^j s \partial^k t$.  And similarly when $x$ is is function of more than two variables.

Comment: If the image of $x$ is $m$-dimensional, then the image of $F$ must also be $m$-dimensional. "0" in $F(\ldots)=0$ is the $m$-dimensional null vector in this case. Example: $Ax-x' =0$ in which $A$ is a $m\times m$ matrix.

Comment: For Reinhard: Ah yes. I forgot that it was a convention of our class. Our teacher said that if he wrote simply x, it was to say all its components. x means x_1, x_2 x_3 etc. For Gedgar: Can you write it in a form of F that I mentioned?